# When I run "heroku open" for my django app, the page says "Application error"

Tags: django, heroku

When I run "heroku open" the page says

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details
```

I checked my heroku logs and there seems to be some error in purple that says

```
2016-03-30T12:46:00.756708+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App  crashed" method=GET path="/" host=alto-vera.herokuapp.com request_id=918f4847- 622a-42b8-8ffd-e7045ce7f987 fwd="67.86.106.244" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-30T12:46:01.307777+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App    crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=alto-vera.herokuapp.com    request_id=88779897-4ddc-437c-9d8b-e9378dee3c09 fwd="67.86.106.244" dyno= connect=    service= status=503 bytes=
```

I only understand that ut says the app crashed beyond that I don't know. If someone can provide guidance I would appreciate it

EDIT

requirements.txt

```
dj-database-url==0.4.0
Django==1.9.4
gunicorn==19.4.5
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
django-crispy-forms==1.6.0
django-haystack==2.4.1
django-taggit==0.18.0
Pillow==3.1.1
psycopg2==2.6.1
pysolr==3.4.0
pytz==2016.1
requests==2.9.1
whitenoise==3.0
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi --log-file -
```

settings.py

```
"""
    Django settings for mysite project.

    Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.4.

    For more information on this file, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

    For the full list of settings and their values, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
    """

    import os
    import dj_database_url

    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    SECRET_KEY = '3iiooiiiooiijju&(mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm'

    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = True

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ]

    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }


    # Password validation
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]


    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

    USE_I18N = True

    USE_L10N = True

    USE_TZ = True


    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

    PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    # Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
    )

    db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
    DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

    # Simplified static file serving.
    # https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/

    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

wsgi

```
    """
    WSGI config for mysite project.

    It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

    For more information on this file, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/
    """

    import os

    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

    application = get_wsgi_application()
    application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

an error message i just noticed

```
ImportError: No module named mysite.wsgi
```

and

```
        2016-03-30T13:18:32.819542+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-03-30 13:18:32 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
    2016-03-30T13:18:32.843958+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-03-30 13:18:32 +0000] [3] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
    2016-03-30T13:18:32.844225+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-03-30 13:18:32 +0000] [3] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

my directory

```
mysite\
   mysite\
       static\
       staticfiles\
       __init__.py
       settings.py
       urls.py
       wsgi.py
   db.sqlite
   manage.py
   Procfile
   requirements.txt
```

Comment: Post the contents of your `Procfile`, `requirements.txt`

Comment: Is your wsgi file actually just called wsgi, or is that a typo?  it should be called wsgi.py

Comment: it was a typo. i made a mistake typig so fast